# Division rings arising from the endomorphism ring of a simple module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I was reading about Schur's Lemma and I immediately asked myself: is every skew-field the endomorphism ring of some simple module?

The page on division rings on Wikipedia states the following:

> In general, if R is a ring and S is a simple module over R, then, by
>   Schur's lemma, the endomorphism ring of S is a division ring; **every
>   division ring arises in this fashion from some simple module**.

How can the latter statement be proven?

Thank you

Comment: If $R$ is allowed to be non-commutatitive, then one can take $S$ as a right-$S$ module, which is simple, and the endomorphism ring is isomorphic to $S$ (acting by left multiplication), so this would be a trivial statement. I'm not sure that is intended though.

Comment: No, the statement is slightly less trivial. We start with a division ring D, we want to find a simple module whose endomorphism ring is isomorphic to D.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $D$ be a division ring and consider $D$ as a right module over itself. Now consider the endomorphism ring of this module. If $s$ is some endomorphism, then $s(1) = a = a1$ for some $a\in D$ so the map $x \mapsto s(x) - ax$ is a morphism with non-trivial kernel, and hence $0$. This means that $s$ is simply multiplication by $a$ from the left, and we get that the endomorphism ring of $D$ as a module over itself is isomorphic to $D$.

Comment: Very clear answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have a concern, is D, considered as a D-module, simple?

Comment: Yes, as a $D$-submodule of $D$ is an ideal of $D$, the module is simple (any element is invertible from both sides, so $D$ has no non-trivial ideals).

Comment: Be careful with non-commutativity issues! Left multiplication by $a$ is in general not a $D$-endomorphism of $D$. Right multiplication by $a$ is an endomorphism but the map $a \mapsto $ "right multiplication by $a$" is not a homomorphism of rings.

Comment: @marlu, the only problem here is that the endomorphism ring of $D$ as a left $D$-module is $D^{\mathrm{op}}$, so one can simply start with $D^{\mathrm{op}}$.

Comment: Edited to make it clear from what side one needs to consider $D$ as a module over itself for the above to be true. (One could also have it as a left module and look at $s(x) - xa$ instead).

Comment: This is precisely what I had in mind in my comment to the question. I have some hesitation with the formulation "arises in this way" though, since that usually refers to a method to obtain something if you don't know about it already, and that is not the case here. It is like saying that every field arises as endomorphism ring of a vector space; it's not false but it isn't very helpful either.

Answer (score 3):

If $D$ is a division ring, then it is naturally an $\operatorname{End}_D(D)$-module where multiplication is given by evaluation:
$$\phi .d := \phi(d).$$
Every element $d \in D$ defines a map "left multiplication by $d$"
$$m_d: D \to D, x \mapsto dx$$
which commutes with all $\phi \in \operatorname{End}_D(D)$, i.e. $m_d$ is an endomorphism of $D$ as an $\operatorname{End}_D(D)$-module. Now it easy to show that
\begin{align*}
\alpha: D &\longrightarrow \operatorname{End}_{\operatorname{End}_D(D)}(D),\\
d &\longmapsto m_d
\end{align*}
is an isomorphism of rings (the inverse sends $\theta$ to $\theta(1)$). So $D$ is the endomorphism ring of some module. We just have to show that $D$ is simple as an $\operatorname{End}_D(D)$-module. This is where we use that $D$ is a division ring. Suppose $E \subseteq D$ is a non-trivial $\operatorname{End}_D(D)$-submodule of $D$, i.e. $\phi(E) \subseteq E$ for all $\phi \in \operatorname{End}_D(D)$. Pick an $0 \neq e \in E$. Then for every $d \in D$ right multiplication by $e^{-1}d$ 
$$D \to D, x \mapsto xe^{-1}d$$
is an $D$-endomorphism of $D$ and its image contains $d = ee^{-1}d$. So in fact $E =D$.